# Consulta MySQL datos repetidos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando una consulta en phpMyadmin, todo funcionaba bien, pero ocupaba datos de otras tablas, sin embargo al agregar los LEFT JOIN todo seguia en perfecto funcionamiento. El problema radica cuando en el SELECT coloco el nombre de la columna a mostrar (**TAVA_MCONV**, o cualquier otro), alli es cuando se genera la duplicación de los resultados.

dejo aqui abajo la consulta que no genera duplicidad

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TPRE_IDPRE), TPRO_NOMBR,TPRE_NPRED,TPRE_UBICA,TPRE_RPROP,TPRE_KMINI,
          TPRE_KMFIN,TPRE_LONGI,TPRE_MUPIO,TPRE_SUADI,TGES_GES01,
          TGES_GES02,TGES_GES03,TGES_GES04,TGES_GES05,TGES_GES06,
          TGES_GES07,TGES_GES08,TGES_GES09,TGES_GES10,TGES_GES11,
          TGES_GES12,TGES_GES13,TGES_GES14,TGES_GES15,TGES_GES16,
          TGES_GES17,TGES_GES18,TGES_GES19,TGES_GES20,TGES_GES21,
          TGES_GES22,TGES_GES23,TGES_GES24
          FROM tpredio AS tpre  
          INNER JOIN tpred_prop AS tpp ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tpp.TPRP_IDPRE
          INNER JOIN tpropietario AS tpro ON tpp.TPRP_IDPRO=tpro.TPRO_IDPRO
          INNER JOIN tobra AS tob ON tob.TOBR_IDOBR=tpre.TPRE_IDOBR
          INNER JOIN tgestoria AS tges ON tges.TGES_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN trecursos AS trec ON trec.TREC_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN tpago AS tpa ON tpa.TPAG_IDREC=trec.TREC_IDREC
          LEFT JOIN tavaluo AS tava ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tava.TAVA_IDPRE
          WHERE tpre.TPRE_IDOBR='6L4E1'
          ORDER BY tpre.TPRE_KMINI
```

esta es la que si genera la duplicidad

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TPRE_IDPRE), TPRO_NOMBR,TPRE_NPRED,TPRE_UBICA,TPRE_RPROP,TPRE_KMINI,
          TPRE_KMFIN,TPRE_LONGI,TPRE_MUPIO,TPRE_SUADI,TGES_GES01,
          TGES_GES02,TGES_GES03,TGES_GES04,TGES_GES05,TGES_GES06,
          TGES_GES07,TGES_GES08,TGES_GES09,TGES_GES10,TGES_GES11,
          TGES_GES12,TGES_GES13,TGES_GES14,TGES_GES15,TGES_GES16,
          TGES_GES17,TGES_GES18,TGES_GES19,TGES_GES20,TGES_GES21,
          TGES_GES22,TGES_GES23,TGES_GES24,TAVA_MCONV
          FROM tpredio AS tpre  
          INNER JOIN tpred_prop AS tpp ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tpp.TPRP_IDPRE
          INNER JOIN tpropietario AS tpro ON tpp.TPRP_IDPRO=tpro.TPRO_IDPRO
          INNER JOIN tobra AS tob ON tob.TOBR_IDOBR=tpre.TPRE_IDOBR
          INNER JOIN tgestoria AS tges ON tges.TGES_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN trecursos AS trec ON trec.TREC_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN tpago AS tpa ON tpa.TPAG_IDREC=trec.TREC_IDREC
          LEFT JOIN tavaluo AS tava ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tava.TAVA_IDPRE
          WHERE tpre.TPRE_IDOBR='6L4E1'
          ORDER BY tpre.TPRE_KMINI
```

imagen correspondiente a consulta 1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

imagen correspondiente a consulta 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Qué quieres decir con que se duplican los resultados, todos los resultados o los resultados en esa columna que agregas? En teoría debería mostrarte la misma cantidad de filas con o sin esa columna. Por cierto, conviene siempre poner a cada columna el nombre o alias de su respectiva tabla.

Comment: Intente subir una imagen pero no las muestra

con duplicados quiero decir que el registro 1 se muestra 2 o mas veces, con exactamente los mismos datos. Igual para los demás registros. 
sobre el alias, los tengo con su respectivos alias, solo que lo borre al publicarlos en preguntas, para que no se viera tan rebuscado

Comment: Me permití poner las imágenes en la misma pregunta. Las pusiste en el espacio de las respuestas, lo cual no es correcto. Ese espacio es para aportar respuestas solamente. Todo dato adicional a la pregunta se debe agregar en la parte dedicada a ello, editándola. En cuanto a la parte de abajo, sugiero que la elimines.

Comment: gracias, en cuanto se habilite la opción de eliminar respuesta lo hago

Comment: En cuanto al problema planteado, me parece extraño que el hecho de agregar una columna te duplique ciertas filas, nunca había visto que eso ocurriese. ¿Seguro que es la misma consulta nada más agregando esa columna? Otra cosa a probar sería cambiar en el `SELECT` esto: `DISTINCT(TPRE_IDPRE)` por esto: `TPRE_IDPRE` y agregar esa columna en un `GROUP BY TPRE_IDPRE`. Quizá funcione, pero me temo que no será una consulta que cumpla el estándar de agrupación de SQL (la actual tampoco lo cumple con el `DISTINCT`) y quizá tu problema sea de normalización más que la consulta en sí.

Comment: Concuerdo contigo tanto en el de normalización y sobre mi problema de duplicidad. Realmente se me hace extraño de igual forma, es como si el [DISTINCT] fuera ignorado totalmente.Pero llevare acabo tus sugerencias y notificare el resultado

Comment: @A.Cedano te agradezco, dado a que funcionó gracias a tu sugerencia, me gustaría que lo pusieras como respuesta para así poderte calificar

Comment: prueba la normalizacion en tu sentencia Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una manera de evitar filas repetidas sería hacer un `GROUP BY TPRE_IDPRE`, quitando el `DISTINCT`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
          TPRE_IDPRE, TPRO_NOMBR,TPRE_NPRED,TPRE_UBICA,TPRE_RPROP,TPRE_KMINI,
          TPRE_KMFIN,TPRE_LONGI,TPRE_MUPIO,TPRE_SUADI,TGES_GES01,
          TGES_GES02,TGES_GES03,TGES_GES04,TGES_GES05,TGES_GES06,
          TGES_GES07,TGES_GES08,TGES_GES09,TGES_GES10,TGES_GES11,
          TGES_GES12,TGES_GES13,TGES_GES14,TGES_GES15,TGES_GES16,
          TGES_GES17,TGES_GES18,TGES_GES19,TGES_GES20,TGES_GES21,
          TGES_GES22,TGES_GES23,TGES_GES24,TAVA_MCONV
          FROM tpredio AS tpre  
          INNER JOIN tpred_prop AS tpp ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tpp.TPRP_IDPRE
          INNER JOIN tpropietario AS tpro ON tpp.TPRP_IDPRO=tpro.TPRO_IDPRO
          INNER JOIN tobra AS tob ON tob.TOBR_IDOBR=tpre.TPRE_IDOBR
          INNER JOIN tgestoria AS tges ON tges.TGES_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN trecursos AS trec ON trec.TREC_IDPRE=tpre.TPRE_IDPRE
          LEFT JOIN tpago AS tpa ON tpa.TPAG_IDREC=trec.TREC_IDREC
          LEFT JOIN tavaluo AS tava ON tpre.TPRE_IDPRE=tava.TAVA_IDPRE
WHERE tpre.TPRE_IDOBR='6L4E1'
GROUP BY TPRE_IDPRE
ORDER BY tpre.TPRE_KMINI
```

De todos modos, aunque te muestre los datos que esperas, puede que la consulta no cumpla con el estándar SQL de agrupación. Es muy probable que en vez de un problema de consulta en sí tengas un problema de *normalización* de los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es hacer el inner join sobre una subconsulta, pero no muestras la estructura de tus tablas, asi que no puedo saber de que forma es la apropiada.

```
SELECT tabla1 INNER JOIN (SELECT campo FROM Tabla2);
```

Entre parentesis te recomendaria un select distinct sobre resultados sin duplicidad), y fuera todo lo demas.